# How to save and show custom images on Vaadin Flow?

Tags: java, database, image, vaadin

I'm trying to implement custom images on my app. Some added by the users and some added by myself on the database. At the moment i'm compiling all resources on a jar and deploying on the server. But I want to work on the images without the need to keep updating the app. It will also be the same implementation as when a user uploads a profile picture and other users see the same picture.

I found this guide here: https://vaadin.com/blog/saving-and-displaying-images-using-jpa but I don't want to save the images as a byte on the database, I want to do it as the first common method it says there: **Storing the image in a folder and saving the path in the database**. That way I can have in my server organized folders with all the images that are stored by my users and by myself for other purposes.

I couldn't find any documentation or guide on how to do this with vaadin flow and spring boot.

Comment: In your question it is not clear whether your images must be background images. If not, it should be easy to use Vaadin's Image component with a Resource served by Vaadin.

Comment: It should be background images @TatuLund, it should be the same implementation as if an user uploads a custom image to the server. It's something pretty basic but I can't find a way to do it. I found this guide: https://vaadin.com/blog/saving-and-displaying-images-using-jpa but what I really want is the first method of that: Storing the image in a folder and saving the path in the database.

Comment: @MrRene Post your clarifications as edits to the Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: I did that already @BasilBourque